# C# Calculator, Equal button won't perform operation on second click

Tags: c#, .net

I'm building calculator (similar to win10 standard calculator), and problem is when you click equal button twice or more. I'm getting second argument from textBox and every time you click equal button it changes it's text value.

e.g when you type 10 + 5 = 15 and then you press button again it shows 25 instead of 20 and so on.

```
    private void buttonEqual(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        secondArg = Convert.ToDouble(textBox1.Text);

        switch (oper) {

            case "+":
                    result = firstArg + Convert.ToDouble(label7.Text);
                    textBox1.Text = result.ToString();
                    label3.Text = firstArg.ToString();
                break;

            case "-":
                    result = firstArg - secondArg;
                    textBox1.Text = result.ToString();
                    label3.Text = result.ToString();
                break;

            case "*":
                    result = firstArg * secondArg;
                    textBox1.Text = result.ToString();
                    label3.Text = result.ToString();
                break;

            case "/":
                    result = firstArg / secondArg;
                    textBox1.Text = result.ToString();
                    label3.Text = result.ToString();
                break;

            case "^":
                result = Math.Pow(firstArg, secondArg);
                textBox1.Text = result.ToString();
                break;
```

Comment: You are missing something about the `firstArg` in you code example. And why isn't `secondArg` used the same way for alle operators?

Comment: You don't have any code for `=` shown. What is `label7`? What is `label3`? What is `textBox1`? Please name things what they represent, not just random types.

Comment: You're probably not saving the right operand, in this case 5. It's simpler if you just keep two variables, total and operand. Total acts always as the first operand.

Comment: You need to show more details, show the form you are designing, and how `firstArg` is assigned.

Answer (score 0):

In your `+` case, you set `label3.Text = firstArg.ToString();`. In all the other cases shown you set it equal to `result`. Set `label3.Text = result.ToString();` to fix.

You also don't use `secondArg` in the `+` case, this might be contributing to your issue as well.